# how to selectivity trigger events in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Question:

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
    hello main 
    <div id="sub"> hello sub </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#main").on("click", function() {alert("main");});
$("#sub").on("click", function() {alert("sub");});
```

Here, when i click the "hello sub" text, two alerts -sub and main - are triggered while i want to see only "sub". How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [event.stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) in `sub` event handler to stop propagation of event up the `DOM` hierarchy tree.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/dnG6M/)**

```
$("#main").on("click", function() {alert("main");});
$("#sub").on("click", function(event) {event.stopPropagation();alert("sub");});
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to stopping the propagation on the `#sub` element, you could instead check inside the event handler for `#main` if the clicked element was in fact `#main` if that's more convenient :

```
$("#main").on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target === this)  alert("main");
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yB4ww/)

Comment: Good description of solution. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#sub").on("click", function(e) { //pass in event as "e"
    e.stopPropagation(); //stop propagation from bubbling to the next element.
    alert("sub");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers all work, but my preferred way is to check `$(event.target).closest()` for the non-handled child node in the container node's event handler, to avoid various gotchas. `event.stopPropgation()` prevents higher-level containers from seeing the event, which oftentimes ends up being needed. Checking `e.target` will fail if there's a nested element underneath sub that's clicked instead of sub directly. This approach avoids both issues:

```
$(".main").on("click", function (event) {
    if($(event.target).closest(".sub").length){
        return;
    }
    alert("main")    
});
$(".sub").on("click", function (event) {
    alert("sub");
});
```

Fiddle w/ example of a higher-level container that has an independent event handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/rH5vj/1/